# Ubuntu, Windows both lag while running apps, playing videos, opening files stored on HDD

Tags: freeze

Ubuntu, Windows both lag while running apps, playing videos, opening files stored on HDD

Whenever I used anything that was on my hard disk, Windows would freeze momentarily. It would lag on exploring through folders, loading photos, opening pdfs and what not. While playing, a video would run for some time, freeze and again run, only to freeze again - as if it were buffering. But on playing the same video after copying it to a pen-drive, it would play smoothly. Same was the case with mp3s. Adobe Reader, Photoshop; every single application would lag.

Thinking that it could be a problem with Windows, I decided to give Ubuntu a try. There was no hitch while running live session. Everything ran smoothly. But after installing it, I've been facing the same problems I faced on Windows.

I can't access my BIOS too. Whenever I press the button that's supposed to take me to it, nothing happens. But somehow, it seems, the first priority to boot from has been set to USB.

I am not a tech-savvy and neither proficient at using linux.

Comment: welcome to askubuntu, you likely have a hardware issue, try HDD test app, or an app that fixes bad sectors, hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, RonnieDroid. Ran a test and it turns out that the HDD has bad sectors.

Comment: @paricitchapagain try fixing this bad sectors, i would recommend doing this from a Hiren's BootCD  it will take such a long time, if it didn't fix it, try to cut the parts of your HDD that contain a bad sector (making them unallocated partitions. Or just buy a new HDD. can you mark my answer as the right one? I'll post it now

Comment: @paricitchapagain how is your situation now? what you did? and please if my answer helped you give me a vote up. and mark it as the right answer. thanks

Comment: Do I need to backup everything before running HBCD?

Comment: sure if you want to keep your files, it's better to move them to an external hard disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not because of Ubuntu or windows, it's because your HDD has some bad sectors, try to run a HDD test app like HDD Scan 3.3 to test it, then after you find the bad sectors use and app Like HDD Regenerator(free) to fix it.

if the bad sector is unrepairable, you can try to cut the part of HDD that has it, Make it unallocated.

If all the above doesn't help you fix your problem you have to **buy a new HDD!**

***Note:*** I recommend using Hiren's BootCD for this [Hiren's BootCD](http://www.hiren.info/pages/bootcd)